# How to validate a decimal number in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I need to validate a decimal number in asp.net. I thought to use a RegularExpressionValidator. In case you have another idea just suggest me.
The number must match numeric(4,1) so accepted values would be:

> 1; 12; 123; 123,1; (not good: 1234; 12,34; 1,234)

I tried to use this expression:

```
^\d{1,3}(\,\d{0,1})$
```

but something is not good with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a comma, then the following digit is not optional, so you need to make the whole group optional, not only the digit.

```
^\d{1,3}(,\d)?$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33iav)

`?` is short for `{0,1}`

Comment: thanks for the answer, and for the site too, I did not know that, I used another one.